# ngResource.Delete() is parsing my Guid like an object instead of passing it as part of the URL

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, typescript, ngresource

I am using TypeScript to generate angularjs backed by ngresources for my Asp.NET.Web.API/MVC application.  I have a dashboard which I am using to enable user management for this app in a RESTful way.  I Currently have CRU portion of the CRUD operations working great.  The DELETE functionality is broken, however.

I am attempting to using the Identity value for my member as the parameter for the delete function.  This works like a charm for my PUT verb, so it is confusing why the DELETE verb is causing the GUID to be mangled.

My endpoint is defined as /api/member/{identity}.

Whenever angularJS attempts to delete a user I get:

```
DELETE https://localhost:44300/api/member?0=0&1=a&10=7&11=3&12=c&13=-&14=4&15=8&16…e&27=b&28=2&29=e&3=b&30=5&31=0&32=e&33=4&34=0&35=9&4=a&5=d&6=e&7=d&8=-&9=d 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

My MemberResourceBuilder:

```
public getResource(): Interfaces.IMemberResource {
        return <Interfaces.IMemberResource> this.$resource(this.baseUrl + "member/:identity", { identity: "@Identity" }, {
            update: this.updateAction});
    }
```

My MembersController:

```
module Controllers {
export class MembersController implements Interfaces.IMembersController {
    static id = "membersController";

    static $inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'memberDataStore', 'editorDataStore', 'membersService'];

    constructor(private $scope: any, $rootScope: any, private memberDataStore: Interfaces.IMemberResource, private editorDataStore : Interfaces.IMemberResource, private membersService: Services.MembersService) {
        if (!angular.isDefined(memberDataStore)) {
            Ntier.Tools.logError("MemberDataStore NOT defined.  Controller not properly constructed.", "Error initializing member functions.  See debug console for details.");
        } else {
            //$scope.members = memberDataStore.query();
            this.loadMembers();
        }
        $scope.actions = this;
    }

    newMember : Interfaces.IMember;

    loadMembers() {
        this.$scope.members = this.memberDataStore.query();
        if (!angular.isDefined(this.$scope.members)) {
            Ntier.Tools.logError("Members NOT defined.  Controller not properly constructed.", "Error initializing members.  See debug console for details.");
        }
    }

    selectMember(member: Interfaces.IMember) {
        this.membersService.selectMember(member);
        this.$scope.selectedMember = this.membersService.selectedMember;
    }

    update(member: Interfaces.IMember) {
        alert('saving');
        this.editorDataStore.update(member,(updatedMember: Interfaces.IMember) => {
            this.loadMembers();
        }, (reason:any)=>{alert(reason)});
    }

    save(member: Interfaces.IMember) {
        this.memberDataStore.save(member, (newMember: Interfaces.IMember) => {
            this.loadMembers();
            this.$scope.actions.newMember = <Interfaces.IMember> new Entities.Member();
        }, (reason: any) => { alert(reason) });
    }

    delete(member: Interfaces.IMember) {
        alert(member.Identity);
        this.memberDataStore.delete(member.Identity, () => {
            this.loadMembers();
            this.$scope.actions.newMember = <Interfaces.IMember> new Entities.Member();
        }, (reason: any) => { alert('failed to Delete the user') });
    }
}
```

My IMember:

```
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
```

module Interfaces {

```
export interface IMember extends ng.resource.IResource<IMember> {
    UserName: string;
    Password: string;
    ConfirmedPassword: string;
    IsApproved: boolean;
    FirstName: string;
    Middle: string;
    LastName: string;
    FullName: string;

    Creating: boolean;
    Viewing: boolean;
    Editing: boolean;
    Deleting: boolean;
    ChangePassword: boolean;
    Identity: string;


}

}
```

My IMemberResource:

```
module Interfaces {
export interface IMemberResource extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<IMember> {
    update(member: IMember): IMember;
    update(member: IMember, success?: (member: IMember) => void, error?: (reason: any) => void): IMember;

}
```

### }

### Update

Zhimin Zhang's was right on the money.  I was pretty sure I had to pass an object, but my problem was case sensitivity.  Zhimin's answer worked but I was able to take his answer and morph it into what I felt was a more true to the objects I was using.

In the controller:

```
delete(member: Interfaces.IMember) {
        this.memberDataStore.delete(member, () => {
            this.loadMembers();
            this.$scope.actions.newMember = <Interfaces.IMember> new Entities.Member();
        }, (reason: any) => {
                alert('Failed to Delete the user!  Reason: ' + reason);
        });

    }
```

Then in the resource builder:

```
        public getResource(): Interfaces.IMemberResource {
        return <Interfaces.IMemberResource> this.$resource(this.baseUrl + "member/:Identity", { Identity: "@Identity" }, {
            update: this.updateAction});
    }
```

Note the use of Upper Case instead of lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you passed to the `delete` should be an object, not just an identity:

Use

```
this.memberDataStore.delete({ identity: member.Identity}, () => {})
```

Instead of

```
this.memberDataStore.delete(member.Identity, () =>{}）
```

Comment: I thought I already tried that and got all the properties parsed out into the Query string.  I have not been able to get back to the project but I will verify your answer when I can.  Thanks and sorry for the long wait to comment.

Comment: Thank you Zhimin!  This was exactly what I needed.  I knew I had to have been doing something stupid.  I actually did try changing the case in the resource builder at one point but must have missed one somewhere.  I have been struggling with reconciling naming conventions between JS world and C# world; I have come to the conclusion that I need to just stick to what is comfortable with me.